# Formatting product numbers in a uniform way

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

I am currently trying to format some articles in a catalog. I am doing this using GREP in a paragraph style that's applied to the articles. My problem is that the numbers have so many special situations.

The basic number is
PR-1234 (4-8 characters after „PR-“)

My GREP code to format this number and the cases down below looks like this right now. it works in *some* cases...

```
(?<=^VAR-)(\w+)-(\w+)|\w+(?=/s|$)
```

However, I also need to consider all of the below cases.
In every case, the "PR" needs to be in regular font and the parts afterwards (except "to" and ",") need to be bold.

PR-**12345-ABC**, PR-**12345-CD**

PR-**1234D-11-AB**

PR-**1234DS-12345D**

PR-**12345D-1**

PR-**12.34.5**

But that's not all! What makes it complicated is that in cases like below, all of the triple-or double digits need to be bold *and* italic.

PR-**12345D-*012*LS**, **-*13*LS**, **-*014*LS**, **-*15*LS**

PR-**1234L-*01***, **-*02***, **-*03***

PR-**12345M-*02*XS** to **-*07*XS**

PR-**1234-*01*** to **-*12***

What can I try next?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using GREP Styles here.

Apply **Bold** to

```
(?<=PR-)(.+)
```

Apply Roman (i.e. neither bold nor italic) to:

```
,
```

(comma followed by a space)

and:

```
 to
```

("to" preceded and followed by a space)

and:

```
, PR-
```

Apply ***Bold Italic*** to

```
(?<=-)(\d{2,3})(!\d)(!\.)
```

[image]

It should give you the result you want:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am using GREP styles, yes.
I tried using your approach, however there are some problems with it that I can't quite figure out.  
  

Using the code  
`(?<=PR-)(.+)`
I run into a problem with numbers that are formatted using commas, they end up looking like this:  
  

PR-**12345-ABC,** **PR-12345-CD**
  
The code
`(?<=-)(\d{2,3})(!\d)(!\.)`
  

is not working at all, however I do not have sufficient understanding of the code to know what I should change. Do you have any idea?

Comment: See edit to my answer

Comment: Thank you! The PR numbers separated with commas are displayed correctly now :)

The other code is still not working, though. I am trying to figure out why, but can't put my finger on it...